# FragmentPagerAdapter don't want page titles

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I do not want page titles on my fragment pages, but when I remove the getPageTitle segment, or set the strings to "", there is a space on the top of each fragment that I cannot get rid of.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) in your layout which is what is showing the fragment pages' titles. Remove it from your layout and the space will be removed.